# Remove nested event listeners in JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, class, removeeventlistener

I have an event listener that is added by another event listener that is added by a function inside a class. I want this event listener to execute once and then remove itself.

To simplify the matter, let's assume I have the following HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="redDiv">some html</div>
<div class="blueDiv">some html</div>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript code :

```
class Test {

    constructor(_container){
      this.container = _container;
    }

    somefunc(){
      // some code here
      this.removeEventListener('click',somefunc);
    }

    start(){
      var container = this.container;    
      container.querySelector('.redDiv').addEventListener('click',function(){
        container.querySelector('.blueDiv').addEventListener('click',somefunc);
      });
    } 
  }



let tester = new Test(document.querySelector('.container'));
tester.start();
```

The first problem I came across, is that `somefunc` is not defined at the scope of the second Event Listener. The only solution I have found was to create a new variable `fnc` in the `start` function and assign `somefunc` to it and then call `fnc` instead of `somefunc`.

This made adding the event listener work and the code run as expected but then when `somefunc()` was executed, removing the event listener didn't work because `somefunc` was undefined at this scope.

I tried to pass `somefunc` to this scope by changing the code to this :

```
class Test {

    constructor(_container){
      this.container = _container;
    }

    somefunc(func){
      return function(){
      // some code here
      this.removeEventListener('click',func);
      }
    }


    start(){
      var fnc = this.somefunc;
      var container = this.container;    
      container.querySelector('.redDiv').addEventListener('click',function(){
        container.querySelector('.blueDiv').addEventListener('click',fnc(fnc));
      });
    } 
  }

let tester = new Test(document.querySelector('.container'));
tester.start();
```

Now, the code doesn't generate any errors but the event listener isn't removed as desired. This has probably something to do with the way JavaScript assigns variables, a subject I don't really understand well. But what I'm interested in is how I can solve this matter and be able to remove the event listener once it is executed.

Comment: https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/one-off-event-listeners-in-javascript-92e19c4c0336 in this article have exact thing that u want. please cross check

Comment: Thank you for your help, but for some reason arguments.callee generates an error inside classes, and the once argument could solve this problem, but it wouldn't solve cases where I want to remove a listener from a previous scope or after n executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain the reference of `this`...

```
class Test {

    constructor(_container){
      this.container = _container;
    }

    somefunc(fn){
      console.log('clicked blue div')
      this.container.querySelector('.blueDiv').removeEventListener('click', fn);
    }


    start(){
      var container = this.container;    
      container.querySelector('.redDiv').addEventListener('click',() => {
        console.log('clicked red div')
        // Wrap someFunc in an arrow function to have "this" inside somefunc 
        // reference this class. 
        const func = () => this.somefunc(func);
        container.querySelector('.blueDiv').addEventListener('click', func);
      });
    } 
  }

let tester = new Test(document.querySelector('.container'));
tester.start();
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mpqvfr)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. I am still learning JavaScript and never used arrow functions before, never understood them actually. I think it is time to learn them.